# How to increase the maximum number of control files?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

> ORA-00208 number of control file names exceeds limit of num
>
> Cause:    An attempt was made to use more control files than Oracle
>   supports. The limit is given in the message.
>
> num = 8.

I need to create 11 control files.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly documented that the parameter can not have more than 8 values.

[CONTROL_FILES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams030.htm#REFRN10021)

> Range of values:  1 to 8 filenames

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create 11 control files.

Short answer: You can't.

Why do you feel the *need* to do so?

What do you think these extra copies are going to *give* you?

The only reason you have more than one ControlFile (or any other, significant, file for that matter) is *redundancy*.  If the disk under one of those copies of the file goes Blooey! then your data is safe and sound in one of the *other* copies.

I can't see any reason to have more than two or three copies of your ControlFiles and, if you're storing everything in ASM, which you really should be these days, then you get [additional] redundancy across the ASM disk groups, for free, anyway.